# How do I show content from a plugin using the template the site is currently working with?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, templates, page-template

I am trying to extend the first serious plugin that I am building. I'd like to be able to use it with different sites/templates.

At the moment I designed a custom page that I included with the plugin that outputs a bunch of data that is edited through the plugin. I built 1.0 of this so it looked fine with the theme that was being used while I built the template.

But when I tried using a new theme everything got messed up (I kind of expected that to be honest).

To help answer the question my approach has been the following with this page:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Football Game (Single)
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main">
    <div id="post-area">
     Custom content here 
    </div><!--post-area-->
</div><!--main -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This looks fine on the original template I was developing for, but on the new template (Twenty Fourteen), the nav on the left covers it up, and the nav has no menu items anymore.

I am simply looking for a technique/approach/methodology to make plugin content display nicely in a variety of templates.

Comment: The answer depends a lot on where in the page the plugin data is supposed to show up. And, honestly, I am not sure there is anything 100% bullet-proof that you can do to prevent themes from messing things up.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably messed up cause the CSS styles doesn't conform to the other theme's styles.

As far as I understand your question, I would suggest to send the data in a [custom shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) and post that to the page's content editor field. You can load a custom style for the output with the plugin.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you for responding. I was thinking about a shortcode. The problem is this template displays the next upcoming 10 football games, and when you click on one of the football games it displays more info. So in a way there is a 'games' page and a 'game' page. I see how it is possible to list the games as a shortcode, but the specific game page, I'm not sure how this will work.